# Refreshing Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I'm developing an app that uses fragment. 
In one of these fragments I retrieve data from a remote server and populate a listview. 
But I noticed that if a user inserts a new value and then goes back to the fragment it doesn't show it. 
The fragment shows the new value only after the user closes and reopens the app... 
How can I solve it? I need a way to refresh the fragment every time the user swipes and views it...

This is the code:

```
public class Page2Fragment extends Fragment {

    TestImmagineAdapter adp2;
    Archivio archivio;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // fragment not when container null
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }
        // inflate view from layout
        View view = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2,container,false);         
        ListView mylist = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView); 

        archivio = new Archivio();

        adp2 = new TestImmagineAdapter(archivio.retTitle(), archivio.retArt(), this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        mylist.setAdapter(adp2);

        /*mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                Intent service = new Intent(view.getContext(), Web.class);              
                service.putExtra("href", archivio.getLink(position));
                startActivity(service);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });*/
        return view;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to notify your adapter of the change.

On the update of your data you use:

```
adp2.notifyDataSetChanged();
```